# SSIS execute process task with powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to write files to Azure File Share using the unc path. The script runs as expected when run interactively. But, when run from the SSIS execute process task it errors out and I am not able to see the error message. I am assigning a variable to the StandardErrorVariable, still unable to capture the actual error message. For instance, I am using the below code.

I doubt my error is due to unable to find the required modules on Azure File Share. If I were to reference the required package modules how do I custom load them from the Azure File Share?

Also, how to capture error messages when executed from within the SSIS execute process task?

I have the powershell executable & script saved on File Share.

```
"\\storacname.file.core.windows.net\posh\exe\powershell.exe"

"\\storacname.file.core.windows.net\posh\script\posh.ps1"
```

Tried the below powershell code and none seem to work.

***PoSh:***

```
    #Add-Type -Path '\\storacname.file.core.windows.net\posh\exe\Modules\Az.Accounts\2.7.6\Az.Accounts.psd1'
    $env:PoShModulePath = $env:PoShModulePath,'\\storacname.file.core.windows.net\posh\exe\Modules' -join [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator 
    Import-Module Az   
    try {
        Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "sub_name"
        }
        
        catch {
            "ERROR - Unable to connect to azure subscription"
        }
```

Comment: Hello @pbj. Were you ever able to make progress on this issue? We are stuck with similar issues using SSIS, Execute Process Task and Azure File Shares.